# li click add class active and siblings li remove class in angular

Tags: angular

**please help me this like accordion when i clink li this should add class active then i click next li this should be active and other siblings class will be remove**

```
<div>
    <ul>
      <li class="active-dropdpwn">Dropdpwn 1</li>
      <li>Dropdpwn 2</li>
      <li>Dropdpwn 3</li>
      <li>Dropdpwn 4</li>
      <li>Dropdpwn 5</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

**please help me for angular code**

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li [class.active-dropdpwn]="activeIndex === 0" (click)="activeIndex = 0">Dropdpwn 1</li>
    <li [class.active-dropdpwn]="activeIndex === 1" (click)="activeIndex = 1">Dropdpwn 2</li>
    <li [class.active-dropdpwn]="activeIndex === 2" (click)="activeIndex = 2">Dropdpwn 3</li>
    <li [class.active-dropdpwn]="activeIndex === 3" (click)="activeIndex = 3">Dropdpwn 4</li>
    <li [class.active-dropdpwn]="activeIndex === 4" (click)="activeIndex = 4">Dropdpwn 5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```js
export class AppComponent  {
  activeIndex = 0;
}
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1qcvhh)

You could simplify this a quite a bit with an `*ngFor`.

Comment: li will be more than 100 then we cant write this , may be li will be dynamically added so what will we do>

Comment: You need to make an array and use ngFor to display.

Comment: any another way for this?